# Highlight with Searchkick and Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I installed Searchkick and Elasticsearch for the first time.

I have the basics working and am trying to include the [highlight](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#highlight) feature.

**The Index:**

```
    <%= form_tag books_path, method: :get do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :q, nil %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <% @books.each do |book| %>
          <div class="media">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading">
                <%= link_to book.title, book %>
              </h4>
              <small>
                <%= book.description %>
              </small></br>
              <% if policy(book).edit? %> 
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book) %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= paginate @books %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <% if policy(Book.new).create? %>
        <%= link_to "New Book", new_book_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
        def index
          query = params[:q].presence || "*"
          @books = Book.search(query, field: [:title], highlight: {tag: "<strong>"})
          authorize @books
        end
```

**Model**

```
    class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
      require 'elasticsearch/model'
      searchkick highlight: [:title, :description]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to highlight with Searchkick.

First, include searchkick in your model.  Like so:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 searchkick highlight: [:description]
end
```

Second, include the highlight fields within your controller.  I have a separate search controller for multiple models.

```
    class SearchesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @book_searches = Book.search(params[:query], operator: "or", fields: [:description], highlight: {tag: "<strong>", fields: {description: {fragment_size: 100}}})
        @chapter_searches = Chapter.search(params[:query], operator: "or", fields: [:body], highlight: {tag: "<strong>", fields: {body: {fragment_size: 100}}})
      end
    end
```

Third, include the highlight feature in your search index view.

```
    <% @book_searches.with_details.each do |book_search, details| %>
      <% if book_search.class == Book %>
        <h3><%= link_to book_search.title, [book_search] %></h3>
        <p><%= simple_format details[:highlight][:description] %></p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Don't forget to use with_details in your each loop.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly. Thanks for describing in detail.